# Adding Polynomials Using Linked Lists Java

Tags: java, singly-linked-list, polynomial-math

I am trying to add two polynomials, however whenever my code is executed it returns zero. I was hoping someone could point out to me what I was doing wring and how to fix it. Thanks

```
    public static Node add(Node poly1, Node poly2) {

    float coeff = 0;
    int degree = 0;
    Node polyAdd = new Node (coeff,degree,null);
    while (poly1 != null && poly2 != null ) {
        if (poly1.term.degree == poly2.term.degree) {
            degree = poly1.term.degree;
            coeff = poly1.term.coeff + poly2.term.coeff;
            poly1 = poly1.next;
            poly2 = poly2.next;
        } else if (poly1.term.degree > poly2.term.degree) {
            degree = poly1.term.degree;
            coeff = poly1.term.coeff;
            poly1 = poly1.next;
        } else {
            degree = poly2.term.degree;
            coeff = poly2.term.degree;
            poly2 = poly2.next;
        }
        polyAdd = new Node (coeff, degree, null);
        polyAdd = polyAdd.next;
    }
    return polyAdd;
}
```

Comment: This code only returns in one place and it returns a `Node` - how can it return `zero`?

Comment: Have you tried debugging this code?

Comment: Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: i think it's returning a node (0,0,null) which is 0^0

Comment: well maybe `poly1` or `poly2` is null, but only you can know that

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to add together linked lists poly1 and poly2, and the result is to be stored in a new linked list.

However you are not building the resulting linked list properly.  As you create a new node for each different degree, you do not properly create new Nodes, and link them together.
The code:

```
polyAdd = new Node (coeff, degree, null);
```

erases any reference to the previous polyAdd.

The correct way to keep the linked list in tact is:

```
polyAdd.next = new Node(coeff, degree, null);
```